# Strange "Compilation error: unexpected token: '?'" in Force.com IDE

Tags: ide, platform-bug

For the last few weeks my Force.com IDE (not updated recently) is showing this strange compilation error:

> Compilation error: unexpected token: '?'

As you see in the screenshot there is no ? token in this line.

[image]

I can fix the problem by rewriting it, but that's painful and I would like to understand if and why I seem to write invisible characters so often.

**Anyone out there with similar problems??**

Comment: time to move to Mavens Mate :-)

Answer (score 1):

This problem generally come when you copy something from any PDF file.
That has some invisible character too by which **"unexpected token"** error occur.
The solution is to rewrite your or try copying from any other formats.

Comment: I NEVER pasted in anything from a PDF. Must be something else.

Comment: Microsoft word and other editors also keep invisible characters, For removing it in MS word go in the Home tab, click on the "Show/Hide" icon. You can also press the "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "8" keys on your keyboard to show the characters. Then remove these character while copying.

Comment: sometimes I see this when the offending character is scrolled way off to the right of the line marked in error.